# Why do we need the <Directory> section in the following virtual host's config file?

Tags: apache-http-server, ubuntu-server, virtual-host, mediawiki

[Here](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-mediawiki-ubuntu-20-04-apache-nginx) is the article explaining how to install MediaWiki on Ubuntu Server.

And here's how they tell us to configure the virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@your-domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www//mediawiki/
    ServerName wiki.your-domain.com

    <Directory /var/www/html/mediawiki/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mediawiki_error
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mediawiki_access common
</VirtualHost>
```

I don't understand this part:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/mediawiki/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

My wiki's location is `/var/www/mediawiki/` as you can see from the `DocumentRoot` directive.
There's no `mediawiki` folder in `/var/www/html/`. The only thing that's there is `index.html` file.
So, why do we need that section anyway? What am I missing here?

Also, why do we use `//` in `DocumentRoot /var/www//mediawiki/`? According to the official Apache [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot) we don't need `//` here, but if I run `apachectl configtest` I get `Syntax Ok` and everything works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My wiki's location is `/var/www/mediawiki/` as you can see from the `DocumentRoot` directive.
> There's no `mediawiki` folder in `/var/www/html/`. The only thing that's there is `index.html` file.
> So, why do we need that section anyway? What am I missing here?

It's actually not needed for /var/www (well, it is, but your standard apache2.conf already has it).

The main point of this configuration is to tell Apache to *allow access* to that specific location. By default, access to any file is denied unless the configuration says otherwise. In Apache 2.4 this is normally done using `Require`, while in Apache 2.2 blanket rules (and IP-based rules) were done using `Allow`.

Another thing done by this section is enabling .htaccess file processing using the AllowOverride option.

Your standard apache2.conf will already contain a <Directory> section that grants everyone access to /var/www (and enables .htaccess) and there is no need to repeat that per-vhost. But if your webapp was stored *somewhere else* (such as /home or /usr/share) then you would need a <Directory> section for that.

> Also, why do we use `//` in `DocumentRoot /var/www//mediawiki/`?

Because the author forgot to delete the extra `/` when editing the path. As the <Directory> section suggests, it was originally "/var/www/html/mediawiki", but then they changed their mind.

In most cases (with a few rare exceptions), multiple consecutive slashes in a path mean the same thing as one `/`.

Comment: Why do we need `Options FollowSymLinks`? What does it do?

Comment: It tells Apache to follow symbolic links, if any are present in the directory. (This is otherwise disabled by default in Apache – likely for additional safety, although it isn't a very useful restriction due to being all-or-nothing.)

Comment: Also, what if I set something different for the `<Directory>` section in my virtual host than it is in `apache2.conf`? Will it override the `apache2.conf` configurations?

Comment: I have this in my `apache2.conf` file: `<Directory /var/www/>Options Indexes FollowSymLinks AllowOverride None Require all granted </Directory>`, but when I try to create a symlink: `sudo ln /var/www/mediawiki /var/www/mw` I get: `ln: /var/www/mediawiki: hard link not allowed for directory`. Why?

Comment: You're trying to create a hardlink. Symbolic links are created using `ln -s`.

Comment: The priority of configuration statements is found somewhere in Apache docs. In general, file/directory-level settings should override vhost level settings, which then override global ones.

Comment: I commented out `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks` in `apache2.conf`, then typed `ln -s /var/www/mediawiki /var/www/mw` and the symlink was created anyway.